# Trigo equations

Tags: trigonometry

$3\sin(x) \cdot \cos(x) = \sin(x)$ from $0$ to $360$ degrees

I simplified the equation to

$ \cos (x) = \frac{1}{3} $

Meaning there are 2 answers (1st and 4th quadrant)

I found $x (ref) = 70.528$

However when I got my 2 answers , I found out that it is wrong . Why is that the case?

Comment: what happens when $sin \: x=0$?

Comment: Wherever possible, *factorise*, don't *divide*. Important life advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your equation can be rewritten this way: $sin \: x \cdot (3cos \: x-1)=0$ so the solutions will come from two equations:  $sin \: x =0$ and $3\cdot cos \: x-1=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simplify $3\sin x \cos x = \sin x$ to $\cos x=\frac{1}{3}$. If $\sin x = 0$, then the first equation is true, but the second is not.